Why is résumé the "most favored" spelling instead of resumé (CV/job/career context)?
I look at résumé and I want to say ray-zoo-may instead of reh-zoo-may. Resumé seems more sensible. Is there some rule around é that I don't get?
BTW é is Alt+0233 on a Windows keyboard. The 0233 may need to be typed on the keypad.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9sum%C3%A9

That é is there because this comes from the French verb résumer.
You are correct that the English pronunciation cannot be deduced from the accent on the e in French.  There is no "rule" for that.

If you try looking up the word résumé in the Google online function.  What comes out is "CV" (curriculum Vitae), which is the expression most commonly used in France.

"That é is there because this comes from the French verb résumer." - but that's the first e not the second one. é is pronounced as a long A in French, so resumé would be closer to how we actually pronounce the word in English.
